# Asynctask equal null when change to second activity and comeback first activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, async-await

i have a issue.

I have **two activity**. In the **first activity**, I use asynctask to download file from server, it's ok. I have a button for cancel download. While downloading, i click button "**Cancel**" to cancel download, i use method "**myAsyntask.cancel(true)**" for this. It doing good, but when I change to **second Activity** and after that, I comeback to first Activity and click button "**Cancel**" -> my App crash. I debug and see **myAsyntask** is null when change activity.

How can i fix that? **i want to cancel asynctask when my app change to second activity and come back first activity**

Thank you

This is myAsynctask

```
 public class AsynDownload extends AsyncTask<GetParams, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;


    public AsynDownload(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(GetParams... params) {
        FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(context, true);
        checkDown = true;
        String domain = params[0].domain;
        String token = params[0].token;
        String codeDevice = params[0].codeDevice;

        String strPdf = "";
        String strJsonPdf = "";
        String strZip = "";
        String strJsonZip = "";


        Log.d("getdata", token + " - " + codeDevice);
        try {
            long total = 0;
            long total_pdf = 0;

            InputStream input_pdf = null;
            OutputStream output_pdf = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection_pdf = null;

            InputStream input_zip = null;
            OutputStream output_zip = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection_zip = null;

            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


            strPdf = domain + DOWNLOAD_BOOK + token + "/" + pdfFileId + "/" + codeDevice;


            strJsonPdf = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(strPdf, METHOD_GET, null);

            JSONObject object_Pdf = new JSONObject(strJsonPdf);
            String path_pdf = object_Pdf.getString("DownloadsResult").toString();

            URL url_pdf = new URL(path_pdf);
            connection_pdf = (HttpURLConnection) url_pdf.openConnection();
            connection_pdf.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection_pdf.connect();

            if (connection_pdf.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(context, false);
                btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection_pdf.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection_pdf.getResponseMessage() + ". Vui lòng tải lại";

            }

            int fileLength_pdf = connection_pdf.getContentLength();

            input_pdf = connection_pdf.getInputStream();

            File root = new File(LIBOL_ROOT_PATH + proCode + "/");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            } else {
                FunctionHelper.DeleteRecursive(root);
                root.mkdirs();
            }

            File pdf = new File(root, proCode + ".pdf");

            if (!pdf.exists()) {
                pdf.createNewFile();
            }


            long total_zip = 0;
            strZip = domain + DOWNLOAD_BOOK + token + "/" + zipFileId + "/" + codeDevice;


            strJsonZip = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(strZip, METHOD_GET, null);

            JSONObject object_zip = new JSONObject(strJsonZip);
            String path_zip = object_zip.getString("DownloadsResult").toString();

            URL url_zip = new URL(path_zip);
            connection_zip = (HttpURLConnection) url_zip.openConnection();
            connection_zip.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection_zip.connect();
            if (connection_zip.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(context, false);
                return "Server returned HTTPZip " + connection_zip.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection_zip.getResponseMessage() + ". Vui lòng tải lại";

            }

            int fileLength_zip = connection_zip.getContentLength();

            long lengOfFile = (long) fileLength_pdf + fileLength_zip;


            output_pdf = new FileOutputStream(pdf, true);

            byte data_pdf[] = new byte[4096];

            int oldPercent = 0;
            int count;

            while ((count = input_pdf.read(data_pdf)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input_pdf.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                output_pdf.write(data_pdf, 0, count);
                int currentPercent = (int) (total * 100 / lengOfFile);
                if (currentPercent > oldPercent) {
                    oldPercent = currentPercent;

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
                    i.putExtra("action", ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
                    i.putExtra("BookId", bookId);
                    i.putExtra("BookName", bookName);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryId", libId);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryDomain", libDomain);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryName", libName);
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        i.putExtra("action", ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
                        btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("action", ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("percent", oldPercent);
                    if (oldPercent == 100) {
                        i.putExtra("show_percent", false);
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("show_percent", true);
                    }

                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                }

            }
            Log.d("duythole3", "totalPDF =" + total_pdf);

            output_pdf.flush();

            output_pdf.close();
            input_pdf.close();


            input_zip = connection_zip.getInputStream();
            File rootFile_zip = new File(LIBOL_ROOT_PATH);
            File zipFile = new File(rootFile_zip, proCode + ".zip");

            if (!rootFile_zip.exists()) {
                rootFile_zip.mkdirs();
            }

            if (!zipFile.exists()) {
                zipFile.createNewFile();
            } else {
                Boolean deletezip = zipFile.delete();
                zipFile.createNewFile();
            }


            output_zip = new FileOutputStream(zipFile, true);

            byte data_zip[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];

            while ((count = input_zip.read(data_zip)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input_zip.close();
                    return null;
                }

                total += count;
                output_zip.write(data_zip, 0, count);

                int currentPercent = (int) (total * 100 / lengOfFile);
                if (currentPercent > oldPercent) {
                    oldPercent = currentPercent;

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
                    i.putExtra("action", ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
                    i.putExtra("BookId", bookId);
                    i.putExtra("BookName", bookName);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryId", libId);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryDomain", libDomain);
                    i.putExtra("LibraryName", libName);
                    if (isCancelled()) {

                        i.putExtra("action", ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
                        btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("action", ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
                    }
                    i.putExtra("percent", oldPercent);
                    if (oldPercent == 100) {
                        i.putExtra("show_percent", false);
                    } else {
                        i.putExtra("show_percent", true);
                    }

                    context.sendBroadcast(i);
                }

            }

            output_zip.flush();

            output_zip.close();
            input_zip.close();

            Thread.sleep(500);

            FunctionHelper.LibolUnzip(zipFile, zipFile.getParent(), proCode);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (DetailBookActivity.this.isDestroyed()) {
            String countTimeEnd = String.valueOf(history.getRemainDate());
            modelLibrary.OpenConnectionSQL(ctx);
            modelLibrary.AddBookInfo(idBook, bookName, cover, proCode, author, publisher, libDomain, libId, libName, user, countTimeEnd);
            modelLibrary.CloseConnection();
            return;
        }
        if (result != null) {
            FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(context, false);
            checkDown = false;
            btnDownload.setText("Tải lại");
            btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            File root = new File(LIBOL_ROOT_PATH + proCode);
            FunctionHelper.DeleteRecursive(root);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Có lỗi trong quá trình tải. Vui lòng tải lại", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
            intent.putExtra("action", ACTION_LIBOL_DOWNLOAD_FAIL);
            intent.putExtra("BookId", bookId);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        } else {
            FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(context, false);
            Log.d("tt", "tai thanh cong 1");
            checkDown = false;
            btnDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.d("tt", "tai thanh cong 3");

            String countTime = String.valueOf(history.getRemainDate());
            modelLibrary.OpenConnectionSQL(ctx);
            Boolean result_addbook = modelLibrary.AddBookInfo(idBook, bookName, cover, proCode, author, publisher, libDomain, libId, libName, user, countTime);
            Log.d("addbook", result_addbook.toString());
            modelLibrary.CloseConnection();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Tải sách thành công", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
            intent.putExtra("action", ACTION_LIBOL_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
            intent.putExtra("BookId", bookId);
            intent.putExtra("LibraryId", libId);
            intent.putExtra("LibraryDomain", libDomain);
            intent.putExtra("LibraryName", libName);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }


}
```

This is method i call Asyntask

```
   private void DownLoadBook() {
    if (FunctionHelper.isNetworkConnected(ctx)) {
        GetParams getParams = new GetParams(libDomain, token, UniqueId);
        asynDownload = new AsynDownload(ctx);
        asynDownload.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, getParams);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Không có kết nối internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is method i use for cancel Asynctask

```
 private void CancelDownload() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Thông báo");
    builder.setMessage("Bạn có muốn hủy tải cuốn sách này không?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Có", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(ACTION_FILTER);
            i.putExtra("action", ACTION_CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
            i.putExtra("BookId", bookId);
            ctx.sendBroadcast(i);

            //  llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Boolean checkCache = FunctionHelper.GetCacheDownBook(ctx);
            Log.d("checkCache", checkCache.toString());
            if (checkCache) {

                asynDownload.cancel(true);

                FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(ctx, false);
                llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            File root = new File(LIBOL_ROOT_PATH + proCode);
            FunctionHelper.DeleteRecursive(root);
            modelLibrary.OpenConnectionSQL(ctx);
            Boolean resultDelete = modelLibrary.DeleteBookSQlite(idBook);
            Log.d("delete sqlite", resultDelete.toString());
            modelLibrary.CloseConnection();

            btnDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnXemsach.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Hủy tải sách thành công", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Không", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}
```

This is button to come to second Activity

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (TAG.equals("BOOK_IN_LIBRARY") || TAG.equals("LOGIN") || TAG.equals("SEARCH")) {

                Intent iBookinLib = new Intent(ctx, BookInLibraryActivity.class);
                iBookinLib.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                iBookinLib.putExtra("LibraryId", libId);
                iBookinLib.putExtra("LibraryName", libName);
                iBookinLib.putExtra("LibraryDomain", libDomain);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, iBookinLib, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                try {
                    pendingIntent.send();
                } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (TAG.equals("BOOK_SHELF")) {
                Intent iBookShelf = new Intent(ctx, BookShelfActivity.class);
                iBookShelf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, iBookShelf, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                try {
                    pendingIntent.send();
                } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can check whether the async task is null before cancelling the task

Comment: check parameter you are passing will it be null or not

Comment: show some activity code also so that we can get your case

Comment: Try this, In 
`cancelButton.setOnClickListener{
if(asyncDownload != null){
CancelDownload(); 
}
else{
//May be error handling
}`

Comment: @SharartiKAKA i post my button change to second activity, thank

Comment: @User54321 i want to cancel asynctask when my app change to second activity and come back first activity

Comment: I think you have called your `asynktask` from `onCreate` method of Activity 1. But when you are coming back from second activity to first activity , It will call `onRestart` method followed by `onStart` method and then `onResume` of first activity and it makes your` asynctask null`.

Comment: @duythole- How About Clearing cache When moving from First Activity to Second Activity ? 
 `@Override
   protected void onStop(){
      super.onStop();
 try {
         trimCache(getApplicationContext);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }`

Comment: can you post your error log

Comment: @duythole Is your `llDownloadItem` is visible when you come back from second to first activity?

Comment: @NitinPatel yes, it is visible

Comment: @NikhilSharma, my app crash, i debug and see myAsynctask is null

Comment: @duythole Also `asyncDownload` is downloading start when you come back from second to first activity?

Comment: when you come back to first activity thn its crash right

Comment: @NitinPatel, asyncDownload is downloading when i click to button call method "DownLoadBook()"

Comment: @NikhilSharma, i come back to first acivity and click button "Cancel", it's crash

Comment: yeah if your finishing your first activity thn it will crash only you should use activityonResult callback ,Thanks

Comment: can you give me an example for this??? Thanks

Comment: For downloading,  you should be using Intent Service.

Comment: On Back Press you creating a new Instance of your first activity which is wrong. Read about Activity launch modes. You should be opening the First activity on "singleTask" launch mode and handle your intent in onNewIntent method. You can also make your task static which is not advice-able.

Comment: @muditsen1234, i change myAsynctask is static object and now it's work good

Comment: Then check for null before any context related operation. Context that you're using to create the aysnc task.

Comment: yep, many thanks :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for a null pointer is the easiest solution,

```
if (checkCache && asynDownload != null) {

                asynDownload.cancel(true);

                FunctionHelper.UpdateCacheDownBook(ctx, false);
                llDownloadItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

**EDIT:**

Declare asyctask as static object to retain the object in memory when coming back from other screens.

Comment: but what if he wants to cancel the asynctask , null check wont help in this case

Comment: Thank, but i mean, i want to cancel download while change to second Activity and comeback first Activity. Your code can not cancel my Asyntask, i used to do it.

Comment: Can you try declaring the asynctask as a static object

Comment: Thank, i try declaring the asynctask as a static object, but no effect

Comment: Maybe you can use your application class for this purpose. You should create a custom application class first and create an public object for the asynctask and create a getter and setter. After that you can use this every time when you need to access the asynctask instance.

Comment: can you add this in onDestroy()?

Comment: @NilayDani, i don't add this in onDestroy()

Comment: @AldrinMathew, sorry, i forget declaring at a position asynctask is static, now i fix that and my app is ok. Many thanks

Comment: @duythole Do you mind accepting my answer if you're okay with it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: oh, i declaring asynDownload is static object and my app run ok, and your answer work for me :))

Comment: I mean there's an option to up vote the answer and accept the answer in stack overflow. :)

Comment: yep, i will do it :))